# Android protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { error

Tags: android, oncreate

I am making a Soudboard with a navigation drawer I am getting an error on two things here is the code

```
    package com.example.user.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    Fragment objFragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            objFragment = new menu1_Fragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            objFragment = new menu2_Fragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            objFragment = new menu3_Fragment();
            break;


    }
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final MediaPlayer intromp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.intro);

    Button intro = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.intro);
    intro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (intromp.isPlaying()) {
                intromp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                intromp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer holyshitmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.holyshit);

    final Button holyshit = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.holyshit);
    holyshit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (holyshitmp.isPlaying()) {
                holyshitmp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                holyshitmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer limberthanwatermp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.limberthanwater);

    Button limberthanwater = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.limberthanwater);
    limberthanwater.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (limberthanwatermp.isPlaying()) {
                limberthanwatermp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                limberthanwatermp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer sandpapernipplwsmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sandpapernipples);

    Button sandpapernipples = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sandpapernipples);
    sandpapernipples.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (sandpapernipplwsmp.isPlaying()) {
                sandpapernipplwsmp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                sandpapernipplwsmp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer raisemyweinermp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.raisingmyweiner);

    Button raisemyweiner = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.raisemyweiner);
    raisemyweiner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (raisemyweinermp.isPlaying()) {
                raisemyweinermp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                raisemyweinermp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer alientacklesatreemp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alientacklesatree);

    final Button alientacklesatree = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.alientacklesatree);
    alientacklesatree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (alientacklesatreemp.isPlaying()) {
                alientacklesatreemp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                alientacklesatreemp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer nipplerubbermp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nipplerubber);

    Button nipplerubber = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.nipplerubber);
    nipplerubber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (nipplerubbermp.isPlaying()) {
                nipplerubbermp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                nipplerubbermp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    final MediaPlayer shittalkmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.shittalk);

    Button shittalk = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.shittalk);
    shittalk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (shittalkmp.isPlaying()) {
                shittalkmp.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                shittalkmp.start();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

There is an error on both of the 
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

statements that says onCreate(Bundle) is already defined in MainActivity

Also sorry for the names of the sound file names, they're from a Youtuber which doesn't particularly  censor his videos.

Comment: You must show as exceptions that you get. Without it we can't say to you where the problem is.

Comment: this is a compiler error. take a look on your code carefully, do you see, that right under inner class you've defined `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` second time?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in MainActivity.java
**import android.os.Bundle;**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).